# BOX- API get shared folders/files data from box using the rest API without using Oauth

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to get data from Box api without using the access token, the folder containing data is a shared folder containing files that can be updated by box admin.I want to use the rest api and get the metadata of changed files and use that in the app.

so far i have not been able to access the data without using the oauth auth_token.

is there any way, that i can access the data without using the auth_token(i.e without making the user to log into the app?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the Box API without an OAuth2 access token. The user must authorize your application, or, if you're working within an enterprise you can use an administrative access token (i.e. a 'service' token) to access the data.

Comment: yes thats a bummer, shared folders are not so much shared !

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2 access token is used for authentication and authorization during any Box API call. You need to get access token before making any Box API call. This link provides details about how to get the access token for making API calls.

https://box-content.readme.io/reference#authorize

Comment: i understand the procedure. but its not what i want. I want to have access of the folder without the token.